# Redirect WWW to non WWW, or the other way around?

Tags: php, apache, seo, redirect

Ive just ran an seo audit on my site and received this message...

> Be sure that www.mysite.co.uk and myside.co.uk are not running in
>   parallel.
>
> Redirecting requests from a non-preferred hostname is important
>   because search engines  consider URLs with and without "www" as two
>   different websites.
>
> Once your preferred domain is set, use a 301 redirect for all traffic
>   to your non-preferred domain.

Now my website works with both www. and without the www. so does this mean my sites running in parallel?

If so how do i address this? and shall i point my non www to the www or the other way around?

Im using PHP on a linux/apache server.

Comment: I'd say non-www is preferred. But that's just my uninformed opinion. SO seems to do that, for instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer on *how* to do this is ridiculously easy to find on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=hp&tok=Okx4TNXX5SXxpZfFA5Ja1Q&cp=13&gs_id=1e&xhr=t&q=redirect+www+to+non+www&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=redirect+www+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k&fp=b6f1c05b19c7f2c0&biw=1235&bih=683). In terms of which one, it's personal preference. I prefer non-www, I find the www redundant unless you're using load balancers. Voting to close as this will only solicit debate.

Comment: http://no-www.org/ and http://www.www.extra-www.org/ are relevant here.

Comment: I would prefer non-www as it is quicker to type on my mobile device and links to your site is shorter and more readable

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger but since there is redirection, you can still type the non-www and get to the site, right?

Comment: @Shomz yeah, but you still need to handle session and cookie stuff. Personally I'm a user that often like to type in the url instead of looking it up. As I said, it's my preference as a user, but not a "Big Deal" :-)

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger Oh yeah, that's what I meant actually: so you type directly `site.com` and get redirected to `www.site.com` and that's all you have to worry about. It doesn't really matter from users' perspective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Now my website works with both www. and without the www. so does this
>   mean my sites running in parallel?

Pretty much. Running in parallel means that a visitor (human or search engine robot) can access same content with www and non-www version of the URL.

The recommended practice is to have both hostnames active but redirect all traffic of the non-preferred hostname to the preferred one using 301 redirect.

> If so how do i address this?

For Apache, place these rules in the `.htaccess` file located in the wwwroot directory:

```
#########################
# redirect no-www to www
#########################

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

-- or --

```
#########################
# redirect www to no-www
#########################

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

> and shall i point my non www to the www or the other way around?

There is no definite answer; both have their pros and cons. See [Yes WWW](http://www.yes-www.org/) to understand why having a www URL is good, and its competitor [No WWW](http://no-www.org/) which simply says *"www. is deprecated."* without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, keep available `www` and `no-www` versions for a web site can be hasardous because it generates duplicate content between two versions of your web site. And Google doesn't like duplicate content, that's why it's good seo pratice to redirect `www` to `no-www` or the opposite.

With Apache Server, you can create .htaccess file (in root of your domain) and insert these lines to redirect ([301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633)) `www` to `no-www`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You also can choose the opposite (redirect from `no-www` to `www`) if you prefer. No matter  for seo if you choose one or other solution.

Comment: For the duplicate content issue please refer to Google's canonical explanation. If the current url is not the permanent link you want to be listed, you should add this tag to the header: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect non-www to www using the .htaccess file:

Here is how to do it and some other useful tricks:
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: Which direction to redirect is a disputed matter of opinion.

Comment: I actually prefer to redirect the www to the non-www, although as @ceejayoz says it is a matter of opinion

Comment: @adam Just of curiosity, does it matter which way you do it?

Comment: I just think it's a clearer look - having www is largely vestigial

Comment: @Oskwish It's pretty much entirely aesthetic. Important thing is both working and one being canonical.

Answer (score -4):

www in www.domain.com is subdomain which can be anything. like ( m.domain.com , x.domain.com or anything.

But usually as per conventional approach www is default subdomain of any site.

Most of the sites refer www.sitename.com or sitename.com to   same page.

So don't worry just go ahead..!!