# How do I make sure my site loads with and without www?

Tags: .htaccess

I work on a site that loads fine with wwww in the URL: http://wwww.flowerwood.com, however, if I remove the www Chrome cannot find the site.

I tried adding an .htaccess rule based on this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245668/redirect-www-to-non-www-or-the-other-way-around) but Chrome still gives an error.

This is the code I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

What is the correct way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a DNS problem, not just an htaccess problem.

```
[~]$ nslookup www.flowerwood.com
Server:         10.1.1.10
Address:        10.1.1.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.flowerwood.com
Address: 192.254.149.221

[~]$ nslookup flowerwood.com
Server:         10.1.1.10
Address:        10.1.1.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find flowerwood.com: No answer
```

You need to register an `A` record for your domain, not just your `www` host.

Comment: Hi, this is very curious. The site has been working for some time. I'll look into the DNS issues and see what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add www always you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

BUt I am not sure why is chrome using `wwww` In case you want to force `wwww` use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wwww\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://wwww.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To non www version use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect www to non www version of your site and you will be able to handle duplicate content issue.